# rotate animation in imageview

Tags: android, android-animation

i try to rotate imageview with animation.i wrote some code.this is a my xml animation code

```
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite" />
```

and this is a java code

```
     final ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rot);
     final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator);

     myImage.setAnimation(myRotation);

     Handler ha=new Handler();
     ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             myRotation.setDuration(1000);

        }

    }, 1000);
     myRotation.cancel();
```

i try cancel animation when  Duration is over.but i can rotate imageview but i can't cancel aniamtion
how i can solve my problem ? if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: change it's repeat count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use handler for animation.

Just use this:

animation xml:

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1" 
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

In activity:

```
myImage.startAnimation(myRotation);  //this will stop animation after 1000 miliseconds as `repeatCount` is 1.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it working.it is a possible to check animation spead.i know how to check animation splead,but i mean, animation spead slowled automaticly

Comment: That may be depending on degree and pivot. @Beka

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
myImage.startAnimation(myRotation);  // to start animation
myImage.cancelAnimation(); // to cancel animation
```